# What is the definition of successful deployment in Azure IOT

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

### Backgrounds

We are testing `Azure IoT edge` for the deployment of our `modules` into the `edge device.` We are interested to understand whatever the `module` was deployment successfully. According to [azure IoT doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-deployment-monitoring)
The `deployment status` can be seen on:

> > Healthy shows the IoT Edge devices that have reported back to the service that the modules have been deployed successfully.

### Questions

The meaning of  `deployed successfully` is not cleared. i.e :

- Does it mean that all `modules` are `pulled` and are `running`?
- Or `pulled` its enough for a `device` to reported `success`?
- if the modules need to be `running,` then the question is: for how long. i.e., is it enough for the module to run for 10 seconds? 1 minute? 1 sec?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

deployed successfully means that the modules were instantiated successfully and they can be either running or stopped inside that edge device. Running is set by default. 
Querying their state is performed through the desired properties of the IoT Edge Agent from each device.

For a deeper dive into how edge deployment works, please see the:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-runtime

The edge module from the edge runtime responsible with module management is the IoT Edge agent:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-runtime#iot-edge-agent

The  IoT Edge Agent from each device will transmit the health information of each edge module, through the Edge Agent module twin:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-edgeagent-edgehub

hth

Comment: so if a `module` is pulled,ran and crashed after `x` seconds, does it consider to be a a successful deployment?

Comment: Yes, I would think so. Its crashed state will be transmited by the EdgeAgent module.

Comment: thanks, would it possible that `deployment` has been noted as successful before running the modules themselves? i.e. does successful `docker pull` is consider as a successful deployment?